# Breaker Panel, what is this label?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

So I am trying to identify all of my breaks in the panel.  There is this one that I have no idea what it serves.  I am hoping that someone could shed some light on what this might be referring to?

[image: I cannot figure out what this label is saying, can someone who's more verse tell me what it might be?]

Comment: REFRIGERATOR by someone who can't spell?

Answer (score 1):

### This is probably the circuit for the fridge outlet

The label says "REFERDIGE"(sic) -- whoever wrote it left their spelling at home that day, but their heart was in the correct place.  The use of a dedicated branch circuit for the fridge outlet (vs. plugging it into a receptacle on a kitchen small appliance branch circuit) falls under the (recently expanded) NEC 210.52(B)(1) Exception 2:

> *Exception No. 2: In addition to the required receptacles specified by
>   210.52, a receptacle outlet to serve a specific appliance shall be permit‐
>   ted to be supplied from an individual branch circuit rated 15 amperes
>   or greater.*

Answer (score 1):

So after talking to others - it might be saying refer dine.  So my first thought is that it is referring to the dining room.   I tried the dining room light switch after turning off the breaker and it still worked. Then I tried the outlets and they did not work... mystery solved.  Thanks guys for offering your suggestion!